# ruby model controller object oriented design

Tags: ruby, oop

I have implemented a Paypoint payment into a project I am working on and in the pass I used a class called by a controller to process the payment and act on the response, now i've redone this to process the payment on the before_create callback so that if the payment fails the transction rolls back and I add an error to the model and now the controller code if just checks if the model is save

old controller code

```
def create
 @model = Model.new(params[:xxx])
 if @model.valid?
    if PayPointPayment.authorise_payment(@model)
      redirect_to new_step
    else
       render :new
  else
    render :new
end
```

new controller code

```
def create
    @model = Model.new(params[:xxx])
    if @model.save
        redirect_to next_step
    else
        render :new
end
```

new model code

```
class Model
    before_create :process_payment

    def process_payment
        if PayPointPayment.authorise_payment(self)
            return true
        else
            <add errors>
            return false
    end
end
```

just wondering what the thoughts are on this kind of design is it good or bad or just plain wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than performing the payment via `before_create` it may make more sense to run the payment as part of validation. It might wind up working identically, but the message it sends to the programmer is that validation is a series of requirements that must be met before the model object can be saved, and `before_create` might take care of pre-requisites that need to be performed to allow creating the end model.

Also, if you ever update the model object, it may change the model enough to require revalidation, but `before_create` won't catch that.

Compared against your original mechanism, of course, this is probably a huge improvement in almost every respect -- it would allow your model to be used outside of the original controller without giving away product/content to users who haven't paid. (Say, if you expose a SOAP or XMLRPC or email or REST interface that doesn't run through your controller.)

Comment: cheers for that always good to hear other peoples comments and to verify the path my code is going down